# Интерация по объекту с типом интерфейса

Tags: typescript

Всем привет.
Подскажите как решается следующая проблема:

Имеется интерфейс для передаваемого на бек объекта:

```
interface IBlack { itemId?: string, lastName: string,...}
```

Этот же интерфейс применяется к временному объекту (функция добавления записи).
В коце функции добавления записи есть такой код для отчистки временного объекта, чтобы поля ввода также отчистились:

```
for (var member in newItem) delete newItem[member]
```

newItem имеет тип IBlack
В рамках JS проблем не было. Объект отчищался.

Но когда я начал идти по пути Composition API и выносить логику в TS.
То столкнулся с ошибкой в цикле for

"Элемент неявно имеет тип "any", так как выражение типа "string" не может использоваться для индексации типа "IBlack".
В типе "IBlack" не обнаружена сигнатура индекса с параметром типа "string""

Подскажите как решается эта проблема.

Comment: `for (const member of Object.keys(newItem)) { delete newItem[member]; }`

Comment: @DmitryKozlov спасибо, но ошибка пока та же самая. Только string в тексте сменился на number

Comment: _применяется к временному объекту_ Тогда для временного объекта вместо интерфейса `IBlack` используйте тип `{ [key: string]: any }`

Comment: либо сделайте все поля в `IBlack` необязательными и инициализируйте временный объект через `= {}`

Comment: либо создайте класс, имплементирующий `IBlack` с значениями по умолчанию `class Black implements IBlack` и инициализируйте временный объект через `= new Black()`